# Javascript shopping cart

Tags: php, javascript, shopping-cart

I am considering to build a mini shopping website.There are no payment methods involved, just the total of selected products displayed and maintained. This will be operated by a single person in a shop to make and monitor sales.

The notion is: products should be displayed as large images in pages, and by clicking on them I store them in a shopping cart. Then next page, I could look at total quantity selected for each product and process sale.

Any idea of a good software that is open source and I could modify further on that attempts this case? if not, how do you advise me to start? I thought javascript would be heavily used, and am of course using php as source language.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try this

[TomatoCart](http://www.tomatocart.com)

apart from this so many open source tools are available in market.

Comment: part of this is similar of what I need...example here: http://www.tomatocart.com/demo/products.php?12&sid=v9sia2mafpjhnfhp7533fjpoc1  When you press add to cart it does the animation then update cart total

Answer (score 1):

If this not for an assignment , which need to use row PHP code i would prefer to use Joomla with VirtueMart
[virtuemart.net](http://virtuemart.net)

Comment: nah not an assignment at all...am not even in university/school :D Thanks will check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at addUI Store

http://addui-store.com

I think this will do what you want and it's extremely easy to build a store using their store builder.

If you don't want them to "pay" at checkout they have a "custom checkout" feature which is basically just build your own form, then it can be sent to you via email or however you want.